# Swift - map returns to starting point

Tags: ios, swift, maps

I have a map in my app but when i move the map around, the second I let go, it returns to the starting point. I do not want this to happen..

My ViewController looks like this atm:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
    {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    let location = locations.last as CLLocation

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`CLLocationManager`'s [`startUpdatingLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startUpdatingLocation) sends updates to the User's location to `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`.

> Calling this method causes the location manager to obtain an initial location fix (which may take several seconds) and notify your delegate by calling its locationManager:didUpdateLocations: method.

So then in `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` the region you're moving the map to with `setRegion:animated:` is the location that just got sent, i.e., the User's location.

Answer (score 0):

You set the region of your mapView in the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method.

Once you start to call `startUpdatingLocation()`, it will start to keep retrieving your location coordinate, and your `didUpdateLocations` method will be called, and your mapView will be update by the `setRegion()` in your method.

You can change the value of location manager's `distanceFilter` to a bigger number, so it will update less frequently. By default, `kCLDistanceFilterNone` is used, so your `didUpdateLocations` will be called of all movements.

Comment: Alright this helped me a bit, but I would like to get the users current location when the users starts the app, but then stops updating it, how is this done ?

Comment: You have completely different question from your original question, you should make another post. If you asked how to stop update mapView after it get user's current location, i will tell you to use `stopUpdatingLocation()`, and not tell you to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like I just had to add `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()` to the `didUpdateLocations` function